Manga about a boy that joined in on a VR-like game and was assigned a baby dragon-like creature which ends up being one of the most powerful creatures
I once read a manga about a boy that joined in on a VR-like game and all of the participants are randomly assigned a monster or dragon-like creature, which they can then taken into battle. When he steps up on the podium, he’s assigned a rather weak-looking baby dragon-like creature which ends up being one of the most powerful creatures and can actually change its form.
I cannot find this manga. Does anyone know it? It’s an old one from the early 2000’s, I believe.

Was the boy just playing the game or was he transported into the game?

Kind of like SAO but not trapped inside.
